# How can I disable this element (`.button-contac-send`) if my form field are empty?

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="button-contac-send">Send</span>
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('.button-contac-send').click(function(event) {
    //ajax
...
```

How can I disable this element  (`.button-contac-send`) if my form fields are empty? I need this in validation.

EDIT:

Form:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="POST" id="form">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
        </div>

        <br><br>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
          <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What kind of form fields? input, textboxes? You should show your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
   var formElementsHasValue=false;

   $('form').find('input, select, textarea').each(function(i,o){
      if(this.value!=="")
      {
       formElementsHasValue=true;
      }
   });

   if(!formElementsHasValue)
   {
    $('.button-contac-send').addClass('disabled'); //disable via css
   }
```

Comment: The element with css class `.button-contac-send`is not a widget, so you can't apply 'disabled' to it.

Comment: Edited to remove second argument from `addClass` method.

Comment: @isherwood, Thanks, i didn't noticed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is iterating over your form fields and doing some validation on them.

Just get all values and check if they are empty.

If one of the required fields is empty don't do the ajax submit and just display an error message.

If you post the whole HTML form I could give you a more specific example.

Steve

// EDIT

Since you're already using jquery:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="POST" id="form">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 ">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</div>
<div class='.button-contac-send'>submit</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button-contac-send').click(function () {
        $('.form-control').each(function (index, value) {
            if ($(value).val() == "") {
                alert('Empty at index ' + index);
            }
        });
    });
});
```